# A group with trivial abelianization and a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a group with trivial abelianization having as subgroup a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: "infinite" is redundant here; a group containing $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is infinite. Good question by the way. I am quite sure that there are examples.

Comment: Oh, yes I'm sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the group of all permutations of $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ (as a set).

It is its own commutator subgroup (*i.e.*, it has trivial abelianization): Every permutation that leaves infintely many numbers alone is a commutator, and you ought to be able to construct anything you want as a product of two of those.

Also, it contains $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ as a subgroup, by its action on itself.

(This argument easily generalizes to show that *every* group is isomorphic to a subgroup of something with trivial abelianization).

Comment: Do you mean by the group of all permutations those permutations that have finite support? If this is the case, then $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ does not include into the group. What am I missing?

Comment: @Jim: By "all permutations" I mean all permutations. It appears you're missing those that have infinite support.

Comment: I see. But then I can't follow your argument in the second paragraph. Any composition of two bijections of finite support has again finite support.

Comment: @Jim: I'm not speaking of bijections with finite support at all. I'm speaking of ones where the _complement_ of the support is _infinite_. That's possible even if the support itself is also infinite -- for example for the bijection that adds $2$ to every odd number and leaves the even numbers unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $k$ is an infinite field and $n \geq 2$, then $\mathrm{SL}_n(k)$ is [known](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group_is_perfect) to be an infinite [perfect](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Perfect_group) group. Now $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ embeds into $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ via diagonal matrices, because $\mathbb{Z}$ embeds into $\mathbb{C}^*$ (rotation with irrational angle). But $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ embeds into $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{C})$ via $A \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & \det(A)^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$.

PS: As mentioned in the comments, a much more easier embedding is the following: $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ (in fact every $\mathbb{Z}^n$) embeds into $\mathbb{Q}^*$ via $(a,b) \mapsto 2^a 3^b$. And $\mathbb{Q}^*$ embeds into $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ via $x \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & x^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ embed into $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: x @Martin: Yes, by $(a,b)\mapsto \mathrm{Diag}(e^{a+bi},e^{-a-bi})$, thanks to $\pi$ being irrational.

Comment: More generally $\mathbb Z^n$ embeds into $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Q)$ (or $\mathbb Q^n$ into $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$) by $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto \mathrm{Diag}(2^{x_1}3^{x_n}\cdots p_n^{x_n}, 2^{-x_1}3^{-x_2}\cdots p_n^{-x_n})$